# How to change only the contents inside <div> tag when a link to second html file is clicked?

Tags: html

when i create more html files for a page , i am repeating the header, footer and other common elements in each page.
Is there a simple solution were i can keep the common elements and just load the other elements when the link to each page is clicked.

Comment: One solution is to easily copy and paste the similar contents to the different HTML pages - This does not require a server. Another is to use jQuery ```load()``` function to load content from a different page and replace the content inside the specific ```div``` block. - This requires a server. More info here: [jQuery load() function](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: You can count on <iframe> tags  along with JS in html to target various pages. However, there are many templating engines to exactly do the same but you'll need to use them via some programming languages. Try searching for "Smarty templating engine" for PHP, "blade template" for Laravel